# 2 Identical functions giving separate results? Python

Tags: python, function

I have been trying to make a script that will convert a binary number to decimal and hex. I was able to do the decimal one easily, but as soon as I got to the hex I started having trouble. I noticed on every test run the value would always come back as 0. I decided to try using the exact same code from the decimal converter that I had to make sure it wasn't just faulty coding. The value still comes back 0. Anybody know why? (I use python 3.8.1)

```
def decimal_calculator(binary):
   decimal = 0
   for i in range(len(binary)):
      digit = binary.pop()
      if digit == '1':
         decimal = decimal + pow(2, I)
   print("The decimal value of the binary number is: ", decimal)
def hex_calculator(binary):
   decimal = 0
   for i in range(len(binary)):
       digit = binary.pop()
       if digit == '1':
          decimal = decimal + pow(2, i)
print("The decimal value of the binary number is: ", decimal)
def main():
   binary = list(input("Input a binary number: "))
   decimal_calculator(binary)
   hex_calculator(binary)
main()
```

for example with this code if I put in the input spot: 10010010 the first response will be 146, which would be correct, but the second gives 0. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You capitalized `I` in `decimal = decimal + pow(2, I)`.

Comment: `int(binary_val,2)` will convert binary to decimal,  `hex(decimal_val)` will convert decimal to hex ... just fyi (and `int(hex_val,16)` will convert hex to decimal)

Answer (score 1):

you are sending the same list to both the functions, but in the first functions all the elements of the list are poped, so there are no elements left in the list to go to the second function, hence you are getting 0.

modify the main function as this:

```
def main():
   binary = input("Input a binary number: ")
   decimal_calculator(list(binary))
   h_calculator(list(binary))
```

Answer (score 0):

There were three main issues with your code.

1) You were using "I" instead of "i" which resulted in an error.

2) Your print statement of hex_calculator was out of the function. (Indentation error)

3)You were popping the elements so actual your list was blank before you passed it into hex_calculator.

Your code should look something like this for getting expected output:

```
def decimal_calculator(binary):
   decimal = 0
   for i in range(len(binary)):
      digit = binary[i]
      if digit == '1':
         decimal = decimal + pow(2, i)
   print("The decimal value of the binary number is: ", decimal)
def hex_calculator(binary):
  decimal = 0
  for i in range(len(binary)):
      digit = binary[i]
      if digit == '1':
         decimal = decimal + pow(2, i)
  print("The decimal value of the binary number is: ", decimal)
def main():
   binary = list(input("Input a binary number: "))
   decimal_calculator(binary)
   #print(binary)--> for getting idea of the list.
   hex_calculator(binary)
main()
```

Your output will be as shown in the image.

[image: Output image]